# Autoload/PHPUnit not found by PhpStorm with Docker Desktop + Docker Compose + WSL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm, wsl-2

My PHP project is stored in WSL, accessed by PhpStorm installed on Windows and running with Docker Desktop installed on Windows.

The Project itself is totally fine, but running Tests is not possible because PhpStorm cannot find the vendor autoload or `phpunit.phar` in **Test Framework** configuration.

Setup:

- Windows 10 with WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- PhpStorm on Windows
- Docker Desktop on Windows, Docker Compose files in WSL
- Code in home folder in WSL (see following screens)

I read in some older threads that Docker Compose v2 needs to be enabled in Docker Desktop. It is:

[image]

Docker is configured inside of PhpStorm and shows that the connection is successful (I know that works because things like Xdebug is working without any issues):

[image]

Notice that I configured a path mapping here for the project root.

- in WSL: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\USERNAME\workspace\PROJECTNAME-web-docker`
- in Docker: `/var/www/PROJECTNAME-web`

I can see that those paths are correct by either logging into the Docker container or by checking the **Service** Tab of PhpStorm and inspecting files:

[image]

This is my CLI Interpreter using the docker-compose configuration:

[image]

1. It does not matter if I use the existing container or if it should be starting a new one
2. PHP Version is always detected

And finally the error inside of **Test Framework**:

[image]

Here I tried different things:

- use composer autoloader or phpunit.phar
- it doesn't matter if I use a full path `/var/www...` or just `vendor/...`
- tried different path mappings here
- clicking on refresh shows this error in a small popup

  > Cannot parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open input file: `/var/www/PROJECTNAME-web/SUBTOPIC/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

`autoload.php` is definitely available and correct, phpunit is installed and available.

Maybe someone has a hint what is missing or wrong? Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
How do I know that autoload is available or path mapping is correct?
I have Xdebug configured and running. When Xdebug stops in my code, I know that the path mapping is correct. The output of `Debug` -> `Console` for example shows stuff like this:

```
PHP Deprecated: YAML mapping driver is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0, please migrate to annotation or XML driver. in /var/www/PROJECTNAME-web/SUBTOPIC/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/YamlDriver.php on line 62
```

so I know the path mapping for xdebug works, but seems like Test Framework config does not like it.

Comment: You must use absolute paths, but i am not sure if you are using Laravel or other framework (or not framework at all, that would be crazy). Are you sure the full path to the `autoload.php` is correct? Did you check if the file exists? I did not modify `Docker` path's mapping, I just left the existing one being `/c/Users` -> `C:\Users`... I would not add your own path mapping...

Comment: I am using symfony. The full path inside the container would be `/var/www/PROJECTNAME-web/SUBTOPIC/vendor/autoload.php`. It exists, either by logging into the docker box or by just using the file browser of PHPStorm **Services** Tab to see whats going on in the container, I can see the file.
Edit: In the screenshot of **Test Framework** you can see that I tested it with the full path in **path to script**
Edit2: I removed the path mapping of **Docker** and added `/c/User` - no difference

Comment: Try this one: instead of `/var/www/xxxxxxxxxx` do `./SUBTOPIC/vendor/autoload.php` (you mentioned you have used relative but without using `./`)

Comment: you are right, I didn't try that. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But thanks for still helping :)

Comment: I honestly have no words what could be wrong, I am assuming you did run `docker compose exec CONTAINER_NAME_HAVING_PHP bash` and then run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` and it did run inside the container?

Comment: correct, yes. Running the tests inside the container works flawless.

Comment: I don't see any sign of misconfiguration. It's worth noting that in the `run` mode, PhpStorm doesn't re-use the existing container but starts a new one, so whatever you see in the running container is irrelevant. However, since the mappings are the same for both the existing and the new containers, the `phpunit` executable should be found okay. I suggest that you add `#com.jebrains.php` to *Help | Diagnostic Tools | Debug Log Settings*, try refreshing the PHPUnit version, and then send the logs (*Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data*) in a support ticket to us (*Help | Contact Support*)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I created diagnostic data with logs and sent them via contact support. Let's see what might cause it :)
One thing I noticed: _Build, Execution. Deployment_ | _Docker_ | _Tools_ also has a Docker Compose v2 checkbox. I activated it as well but nothing changes again.

Comment: Which interpreter is used in `Test Framework`? Delete the `local` one and make sure all the existing configs use the remote one. It should pick up the autoloader automatically, but you can always specify it under `Test Framework` -> `Test Runner` -> `Default bootstrap file`.

Comment: when executing the tests I can see that he tries to use the remote interpreter.

Comment: @Havrin Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Onion in the ticket created for Jetbrains, I tried out some more but nothing worked. After some time, a preview update was released and I was asked to try it out. It worked without any other configuration. So actually the latest stable release should fix it if you use the config like the description of my issue.  
I am currently using it with "Connect to existing container".